# How should I align images to same height but normal width?

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to make a responsive image grid displayed images which are loaded from the server. Here are my code snippets for HTML and CSS which I'm using:

HTML

```
<div class="wrap" *ngIf="Display('images')">
    <div class="imgwrap" *ngFor="let item of items$|async">
        <img src="{{item.link}}">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: auto;
}

.imgwrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 20% 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.imgwrap img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

They currently create each image of same height and width due to which some images are being cropped out.

I'm trying to achieve the layout similar to Google images. The images should be of the same height but the width should be natural (not being changed). It would be great if someone can guide me through this to achieve the desired layout. :)

Comment: You question is not clear. Do you want to maintain the same aspect ratio? Or something else?

Comment: @Kaushal I want to achieve something like this : https://codepen.io/blimpage/pen/obWdgp